# generating a JavaAbstractMethod exception

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

i've written this code for adding photos to database and i'm not much into web application
so please help me out

```
        // obtains input stream of the upload file
        inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();
    }
    Connection conn = null; // connection to the database
    String message = null;  // message will be sent back to client
    try {
         // connects to the database
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/opmdb", "root", "sourabh");

        // constructs SQL statement
        String sql = "INSERT INTO photos (userId, photo) values (?, ?)";
        PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        statement.setString(1, userName);
        statement.setBinaryStream(2, inputStream);
```

here it is telling the error i've also used setBlob but the error remains the same
Exceptions and stacktrace is

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError:com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setBinaryStream(ILjava/io/InputStream;)V
at org.onlinepicturemanager.addphotoservlet.AddPhotoServlet.doPost(AddPhotoServlet.java:81)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: 1) *"so please help me out"* Please find and use your shift key where appropriate.  Using it at the start of sentences helps people to read the text.  Also put it for "I" or "I'm".  2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  3) Copy/paste the error or exception output as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16030814/edit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code `statement.setBinaryStream(2, inputStream);` 
to

`statement.setBinaryStream(2, inputStream,file.length);`

'setBinaryStream'  method need 3 parameteres,add your file length in this method

Comment: i'm using     Part filePart = request.getPart("photo");

Comment: i'm using Part filePart = request.getPart("photo"); and photo is being retrieved by the html form. So how can i put file.length in the third argument or can u suggest me a complete file uploading code

Comment: I;m using Part class to get file from request

Comment: sry,i don't know how  change Part to File...Maybe some other one know this :)